# Quick way to transfer database from production to staging in Heroku?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, production, staging

After reading multiple links from the dev support at Heroku I'm still not sure how to transfer the database from production to staging in the fastest way.

These are some of the links I went over trying to figure it out.

[migrate heroku postgres with pgbackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrate-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups)

[heroku postgres import and export](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

[heroku postgresql](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way is to user the transfer command.

As per Kens answer .. ensure pgbackups addon is part of both your apps then follow these instructions using the pgbackups:transfer

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfering-databases-between-heroku-applications

Code Example:

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE -a sushi
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional version Jonathon.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have the add-ons in Heroku**

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups -a staging_app_name

heroku addons:add pgbackups -a production_app_name
```

**Capture backups. Use --expire if your existing list is full.**

```
heroku pgbackups:capture -a production_app_name
```

**Transfer production db to staging db**

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url -a production_app_name` -a staging_app_name
```

**Notes**
After all that, make sure you are in the correct (staging) folder locally

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Make sure you're in the production folder. 
Those are backticks (`) not quotes. You can find them on the same key as the (~). Top-left of keyboard.

The production_app_name would be replaced with your app name on Heroku. staging_app_name is replaced with the staging app name. (houseofcheese and houseofcheese-staging or whatever you named yours)

pgbackups:url is a command. It does not mean you should add a url like houseofcheese.org